# Kivy Camera Memory Error

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have the following camera code in `kivy` running on a Raspberry Pi 3 with a Logitech webcam:

```
class KivyCamera(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = None

    def start(self, capture, fps=30):
        self.capture = capture
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)

    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule_interval(self.update)
        self.capture = None

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            # convert it to texture
            cv2.putText(frame, "Testing!", (0, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 2, (100, 0, 255))
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)

            if (recON == 1):
                out.write(frame)
            #
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                #size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='rgb')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            #self.canvas.ask_update()
            self.texture = image_texture
```

After around 3 minutes of displaying the frames from a Logitech C920 (on an LCD)I get the `memory exception` below. If I use a Logitech C170 that will run longer for around 5 minutes:

[image]
To me it seems like a buffer is overflowing. The C920 with its higher resolution filling it faster, but I cannot see in my code where a buffer is filling up?

Answer (score 1):

When running the code I noticed this warning:

[image]

When I changed the python line from:

```
image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
```

to:

```
image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
```

I no longer received the `warning` or the memory leak. I swapped the colorspace back using the `cvtColor` feature of `opencv`